# How to read a binary file written in LittleEndian into python?

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles

I have some data written from a physics simulation, which I am trying to read into python.
The data is in a `.raw` file, but I've been told that it is binary encoded in LittleEndian. You can find the data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yp-Virpt2cFE1fRoX6NCt2gR2I3LyTaA/view?usp=sharing
The data should be 120x60 values that are ~9e-4.

I've tried using `numpy.genfromtxt`, but changing the dtype changes the values, and I can't find a dtype that has the correct values.

I've tried using this code:

```
import struct
file = open(path_to_data, 'rb')
data = struct.unpack('float', file.read())
```

But I get the error that `bad char in struct format`. I've tried using `<4` instead of `float` and then I get the error that `struct needs a buffer of 32 bytes`.

I don't understand binary encoding and don't often use it, does anyone have any advice for how to read in this data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read little endian from file and convert to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965862/read-little-endian-from-file-and-convert-to-decimal)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment

Answer (score 1):

Your data file is 28800 bytes long.
If it is 120x60 values, that would make all values 28800/(120*60) = 4 bytes long.

Normally, there are a couple of questions that need answering before you can read the file.

- Is it 120 rows x 60 columns or the other way around?
- Is the data stored row-first or column-first?
- We know the data points are four bytes, but are they `float` or `int`?

However looking at the file, all values seem to be the same:

```
> hd x19_rho_N2-0
00000000  fa ed 6b 3a fa ed 6b 3a  fa ed 6b 3a fa ed 6b 3a  |..k:..k:..k:..k:|
*
00007080
```

From you question I'm assuming they are `float` in little-endian order.

```
In [2]: with open("x19_rho_N2-0", "rb") as binary_file:
   ...:     bdata = binary_file.read()
   ...:
```

Since we don't know row/colum order, just read them into a list:

```
In [4]: import struct

In [5]: result = [r[0] for r in struct.iter_unpack("<f", bdata)];

In [6]: len(result)
Out[6]: 7200
```

This yields 7200 values, but they are all the same:

```
In [7]: set(result)
Out[7]: {0.0008999999845400453}
```

If you *know* the shape of the data, you can read them in that shape:

```
In [10]: result2 = [r for r in struct.iter_unpack("<60f", bdata)];

In [11]: len(result2)
Out[11]: 120
```

or

```
In [14]: result3 = [r for r in struct.iter_unpack("<120f", bdata)];

In [15]: len(result3)
Out[15]: 60

In [16]: len(result3[0])
Out[16]: 120
```

You can read it as a `numpy` array like this:

```
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: result = np.fromfile("x19_rho_N2-0", "<f")
Out[3]: array([0.0009, 0.0009, 0.0009, ..., 0.0009, 0.0009, 0.0009], dtype=float32)
```